# Statistic to Verify Subsample is Similar to Original Sample?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation, subsampling

I have a subsample of data (120 students) that was taken from an original sample of 1,216 students' data. I need to report in my manuscript whether my subsample's key demographics (age, gender distribution, ethnicity, hours of sleep) are still similar to the original sample (the 1,216 students). What test do I run in R Studio to do this?

Specifically, I have the information average age in overall sample 14 (.5) and subsample 12.9 (.44). In what ways could I compare compare?

Comment: What information exactly do you have available from the population?

Comment: I have the original sample's sample size, means, and standard deviation on the relevant demographic variables. Some of these are continuous variables, others categorical (like gender).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have the population averages (so no data or at least variance) then what you can do is perform t-tests or linear regression (`t.test` or `lm`), to estimate your sample averages and their confidence intervals (for each variable). With this information you would check whether your sample confidence intervals contain your population averages. If they do then you can conclude that your sample approximates the population well.